# Convert equation to Riemann sum to definite integral

Tags: definite-integrals, riemann-sum

How do you convert this equation to Riemann sum then to definite integral

$$
\lim_{n \to \infty } \frac{1}{n} \Bigg(\sqrt{\frac{1}{n}} + \sqrt{\frac{2}{n}} + \sqrt{\frac{3}{n}} + ... + \sqrt{\frac{n}{n}} \Big)
$$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** $$\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{r=1}^n f\left(\frac{r}{n}\right)=\int_{0}^1 f(x) dx$$

Answer (score -1):

HINT: It leads to 
$$
\int_0^1 \sqrt x\,dx.
$$